# How to compare dates from separate tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to compare two tables in my database. One of the tables (named ORDERED) has a field called OREDERDATE. Another table (named ORDERLINE) has a field called DATESUPPLIED.

I would like to run a SQL query to return the difference in days between the two dates.

I have tried a few things thus far (for example...

```
SELECT ordered.ordernumber, ordered.orderdate, orderline.datesupplied, 
       customer.customernumber,
       LEAD (orderdate) OVER (partition by customernumber 
                              ORDER BY customernumber) - datesupplied DIFF_DAYS
FROM   ordered, orderline;
```

) ... but to no avail.

Please assist. My ERD follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZhqy.png)

Comment: How are "order lines" from the second table matched with "orders" from the first table? The way you asked the question (without addressing this question) doesn't make a lot of sense. Do you have an order id as primary key in the first table, used as foreign key in the second table? Then: What is the data type of the two date columns (one in each table)? It should be `date`. If so, what is the time-of-day - is it always midnight, or can it be any time of day? And, if the latter, what is the "difference in days" - can it be a fractional number, like 3.5 for 3 days and 12 hours?

Comment: Also, I formatted your code. Select the whole code block and then press CTRL-K, or use the `{}` button from the formatting toolbar at the top when you compose or edit your post.

Comment: @mathguy - I have now edited and attached my Relationship diagram showing all tables, how they relate, and data types of attributes. Time of day is not relevant, and I am just looking for days difference in whole numbers. eg. OrderDate 01/11/2020, DateSupplied 03/11/2020, DIFF_DAYS 2

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select ol.ordernumber, ol.productcode,
       trunc(ol.datesupplied) - trunc(o.orderdate) as days_difference
from   orderline ol join ordered o on ol.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
;
```

This will only show the order number and the product code (therefore corresponding exactly to the rows in the second table) and the day difference between the supply date and the ordered date. `trunc()` is needed to truncate the time-of-day to midnight, since this is what you said you needed.

If you need additional columns from either table, add them to the `select` clause. If you must filter your results (for example, look only for specific orders, or orders before or after a given date, etc.), add a `where` clause. If you need to order the results in some way, add an `order by` clause.